# Can a jQuery animation triggered on hover be toggled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I have a div element that I want to grow in width upon hovering on another div, and then shrink in width when moving off the over div. I have managed to code this for the click function, but can not seem to get it to work for the hover function. Below is my "click" jQuery code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


$(document).ready(function(){
$("#div1").click(function(e){
    var element = $(this),
        clicked = parseInt(element.data('clicked')) || 0;

    element.data('clicked', clicked + 1);
    $("#div2").stop();
    if (clicked % 2 == 0)
    {
        $("#div2").animate({left:"+=97%"}, 500);
    }
    else
    {
        $("#div2").animate({left:"-=97%"}, 500);
    }
    e.preventDefault();
```

Can anyone please advise how to make this work with hover instead of click? I have tried substituting the words clicked/click in the above code with hover/hovered, but this does not work.

Comment: What's wrong with using jQuery .hover()? http://codepen.io/tigran_io/pen/nsJBD

Comment: with the .hover() it only works one way - i.e you hover on the div and it expands the 2nd Div, but then when you move off the div, the effect is not reversed.

Comment: You never read docs, did you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('mouseover', "#div1", function(e){
   //your code here
});
```

Comment: Also you can use mouseenter and mouseleave events

Comment: Thanks Alexey, using the mouseover/mouseout works great. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#div1').on('mouseover', function(e){
  $("#div2").animate({left:"97%"}, 500);
});

$('#div1').on('mouseout',  function(e){
  $("#div2").animate({left:"-97%"}, 500);
});
```

**Try this**

Answer (score 1):

So, your code seems to be a bit more complicated than it needs to be.  Try something like this...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#div1").mouseenter(function(e){
     $("#div2").animate({left:"+=97%"}, 500);
   });
   $("#div1").mouseleave(function(e){
     $("#div2").animate({left:"-=97%"}, 500);
   });
});
```

What the code here says is that when hovering (mouse enter) over `#div1` animate your `#div2`.   When you move the mouse away, animate it back.

Answer (score 0):

Try using folowing:

```
$('#div1').mouseenter(function(){
    // your function
});
```

I guess .hover() not working because it constantly adds 1 to your element.data

Answer (score 0):

`$.hover()` can take 2 functions as parameters, mouse enter and mouse leave, you can drop the `clicked` data thingy this way.

http://api.jquery.com/hover/

```
$("#div1").hover(
  function (e) { // mouse enters
    $("#div2").stop();
    $("#div2").animate({left:"+=97%"}, 500);
  }, function (e) { // mouse leaves
    $("#div2").stop();
    $("#div2").animate({left:"-=97%"}, 500);
  });
```

Something along this line should do it